# How to get all consecutive-letter words between length a and b

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
s = 'HELLOPEOPLE'
```

How would I get all words made up of consecutive letters in the above word between length a and b? For example:

```
get_words('HELLOPEOPLE', min=2, max=3)
==> he, el, ll, lo, op, pe, eo, pl, le, hel, ell, llo, lop, peo, epl, ple
```

Initially I thought to use `chain.product`, but that doesn't obey ordering of letters (as far as I could tell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use itertools to chain together the different length substrings:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> s = 'HELLOPEOPLE'
>>> min, max = 2, 3
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((s[i:i+k] for i in range(len(s)+1-k))
...                          for k in range(min, max+1)))
['HE', 'EL', 'LL', 'LO', 'OP', 'PE', 'EO', 'OP', 'PL', 'LE',
 'HEL', 'ELL', 'LLO', 'LOP', 'OPE', 'PEO', 'EOP', 'OPL', 'PLE']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_words(a, min, max):
    lst = []
    for length in range(min, max + 1):
        for i in range(0, len(a) - length + 1):
            lst.append(a[i:i+length].lower())
    return lst
```